# Wordpress WPDB::insert 13th param is always blank (only if format)

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to insert stuff into the Wordpress-Database it work always very well. I use the [wpdb::insert](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/) function. The function has an optional 3rd param to say which datatype the value has to be.

As I say it works very well but only if you use more than 12 values to insert into the Database it will not insert the 13+ values (they are always blank or null or 0 - depends on the format datatype)

First I guess the value was not set correctly so thats my fault but after playing with these function I found myself more confusing than before.

- If I say param 13 has to be a string its always an empty string
- If I say param 13 has to be an integer its always "0" even if I hardcode the value to an other int value...

BUT:
If i don't use the 3rd param within the insert function (which is the formating array) it works.

Example:

```
$wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_table',
        array(
            'col1' => $value1, // insert value
            'col2' => $value2, // insert value
            'col3' => $value3, // insert value
            'col4' => $value4, // insert value
            'col5' => $value5, // insert value
            'col6' => $value6, // insert value
            'col7' => $value7, // insert value
            'col8' => $value8, // insert value
            'col9' => $value9, // insert value
            'col10' => $value10, // insert value
            'col11' => $value11, // insert value
            'col12' => $value12, // insert value
            'col13' => $value13 // Empty string ONLY if use the next array else it work and insert my value - even if I use a hardcoded value like 'hello world' its empty
        ),
        array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s' // It detect this formating bec. if it is %s it results in an empty string and if I use %d its 0
        )
```

Is this some kind of a bug in Wordpress or has someone similar problems? (yeah i know its unusual to use long insert stuff like this but its necessary at this point)

Its realy weird for me at this point sorry for the may bad grammar...

Comment: Yeah I used already the $wpdb->prepare method but I was just curious

Comment: In order to help, you should answer the question I asked in my comment.  And I think you misunderstand my point - I'm explaining what `insert` does, which means that your problem is most likely NOT due to `insert`, but due to data.  **That's why you should see what the last query executed was** (per my link), so you can see what WP did with your `insert`, and you / we can understand what happened.